# how is the boot directory of the EFI/ESP partition related to the boot directory of the root partition?

Tags: boot, uefi, root-filesystem

are the files inside these 2 directories mirror images of each other?

how are they related? for example the below command that i execute:

sudo cp -a initramfs-4.18.16-300.fc29.x86_64.img /boot/EFI/fedora

is it copying the file to the EFI/ESP partition(sda1) or to the root/system file partition?

thanks

Comment: Suggested edit: do you mean `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora` ?  (In this case, the answer is the command should copy a file to the ESP.  Because the ESP should be mounted at `/boot/efi`.).

Comment: Systems vary.  most likely `/boot/efi` points to your EFI partition.  But you can type `df /boot/EFI/fedora` to tell you which partition is mounted there.  Alternatively just `mount` will list all mount points.

Comment: or `findmnt` instead of `mount` - this a newer command, and tries to make the output easier to read

Comment: so i used this command:

sudo cp -a initramfs-4.18.16-300.fc29.x86_64.img /boot/EFI/fedora 

to copy the file to my ESP/EFI partition. a few days later(i'm not exactly sure at which point in time), the same file appears in the boot directory of my archlinux root partition. why is this so?

thanks